# Bind serverside function with Hyperlink control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code: I am using c#.

```
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("Report.aspx?val={0}", Eval("id")) %>'>Print</asp:HyperLink>
```

What I like to do is something like:

```
     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("Report.aspx?val={0}", EncryptVal(Eval("id"))) %>'>Print</asp:HyperLink>


     protected string EncrypedVal(string val)
     {

     }
```

When I insert the EncryptVal method the code simply does not work  Possibly show me how to insert a method within the NavigateUrl like I am trying to do.

Comment: Can you give more information about what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "Report.aspx?val=" + EncryptVal(Eval("id")).ToString()%>'
```

Try it without the String.Format and just plug the ID value.

If that runs use String.Concat so you don't have the addition sign on string concatenation.

```
NavigateUrl = '<%# String.Concat("Report.aspx?val=", EncryptVal(Eval("id")))%>'
```